# How to run ReactNative Based app on Browserstack-Automate/ App-live?

Tags: browserstack

My Test app is ReactNative based native app (both Android & iOS)
There's the dependency on 'Metro Bundler' in order for data to get populated.
How to make sure that Metro Bundler dependency is run, when tried to access the development app on Browserstack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution to this, here's what BrowserStack support had to say:

> I understand that you're looking to test your React Native application on App Automate and you're looking to understand how to run the Metro bundler when running tests on App Automate.
> ​
> You will be unable to run any server on our devices/machines due to restricted access. Plus, we offer real mobile devices so we expect all necessary dependencies to be packaged to the APK file that you upload to our infrastructure.
> ​

Building your app with `bundleInDebug` set to `true` should produce a `.apk` that doesn't require you to explicitly run your Metro bundler on the server. Following the steps here worked for me:

https://dev.to/nitish173/how-to-generate-a-debug-apk-in-react-native-1gdg

https://celsiusnotes.com/react-native-android-debug-apk-without-development-server/